# Google Analytics suddenly started Sampling Data, 3k sessions for property over time period

Tags: google-analytics

We are using the free level of GA and have been creating reports using Custom Dimensions and Metrics since last summer.

We also use the Google Sheets Analytics add-on to post process data pulled from the API.

Overnight on 16-17 May (UK Time), our reports suddenly started showing as being sampled. Prior to that we had no sampling at all, as our reports are scheduled so I can look back through the revision history to see changes made when the scheduled reports run.

This sampling is occurring in custom reports viewed in the GA platform and in GA sheets. I've done some analysis and it appears to only occur at the point that more than one Custom Dimension is added to a report, or when the GA dimensions ga:hour or ga:dateHour are used (ga:date does not trigger sampling).

All our Custom Dimensions and Custom Metrics are set at Hit level (I've read a post where it was claimed to be due to mixing scopes on Dimensions & Metrics, but we are not doing this).

If I reduce the date range of a query (suggested as a solution on many blogs), the sampling level actually gets worse rather than better.

For the month of May we didn't even hit 4k sessions at property level. I can't find any reference anywhere to any changes being made to GA that would cause sampling to apply to our reports (change documentation, Google Blogs etc).

Is anyone else experiencing this or can anyone shed any light on why this might be happening? Given how we use GA if we can't resolve this then it's a year of work down the drain, so I'm really keen to at least know why this has suddenly happened even if ultimately nothing can be done about it.

Comment: Since the start of June I'm experiencing a similar problem. Suddenly I only get sampled data in queries which used to be okay. Number of sessions way below 500k. No idea, what's the reason.

Comment: Just for info this has been open as an issue with GA for a while now. (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62525952)